# Z3 C++ API: set parameter for tactic

Tags: c++, parameters, z3

I'm using the Z3 C++ API of the SMT Solver and I'd like to change parameters of the "ctx-solver-simplify". I don't know how to input them to the tactic. I tried:

```
z3::context c; 
c.set("arith_lhs",false);
c.set("eq2ineq",true);
```

And

```
z3::params params(c);
params.set("arith_lhs",true);
params.set("eq2ineq",true);
```

Example code:

```
z3::expr x = c.int_const("x");
z3::expr cond1 = !(x==4);

z3::goal g(c);
g.add(cond1);

z3::tactic t(c, "ctx-solver-simplify");
z3::apply_result r = t(g);
```

The result is

```
(goal (not (= x 4)))
```

And not

```
(goal and  (< x 4) (> x 4)
```

Same applies for arith_lhs. Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: How they "Don't work"? For example, what output you get vs. what you want.

Comment: As an engineer, you should learn first and foremost that you need to provide context, that is, to share the implied details of your problem with the others. There are chances that they aren't familiar with the problem or the context surrounding it. So, in this case, you need to explain (A) what is `z3`, (B) what is your input, (C) what is your expected output, (D) what is the actual output.

Comment: As an engineer I try to keep questions as simple as possible. I guess you are not using Z3-smt solver ? Anyways, I updated the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

`z3::tactic t(c, "ctx-solver-simplify");`

to

`z3::tactic t = with(z3::tactic(c, "simplify"), params);`

This will instruct Z3 to apply the `simplify` tactic with the selected parameters.  In the SMT-LIB API this is accomplished with the "using-params" combinator.  I got the above C++ equivalent from `example.cpp` shipped with the Z3 source.

So there were two problems: (1) You need to tell Z3 to apply the given tactic with the selected parameters. (2) the `ctx-solver-simplify` tactic does not have an `eq2ineq` option.  Other tactics do, though, including `simplify`.

Comment: If someone wants to use eq2inq with ctx-solver-simplify, use simplify first on and afterwards ctx-solver-simplify. Not efficient, but it works.